# How to run Driver Tests for Apache Age locally

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

Is it possible to run driver tests locally instead of waiting for a pull request to be triggered? The Apache Age project has four drivers - GoLand, JDBC, Node.js, and Python. I would like to know how to run the tests for each driver individually.

Currently, when a pull request is made, all driver tests are run and checked. However, I am interested in finding out if there is a way to run these tests on my local system.

The project's regression tests can be run using the `installcheck` command, but I'm not sure if there are similar commands for the driver tests. Can someone provide instructions on how to run tests for each driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### OPTION 1

You can update the workflows temporarily to trigger for a commit on the branch you are working. e.g

```
on:
 push:
  branches: ['your-branch']
```

Be sure to remove this before creating a PR on the main repo.

#### OPTION 2

Create a PR on the master branch of your own forked repo before creating it for official repo. This is what I personally prefer btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can run them **locally** for sure, but the **local** run does not make any effect on the **on-cloud** (github) **test**, so that, your test will be just for **you** and the **github** checks are **supposed** to be running on the cloud to ensure the code is working **properly** on a **neutral ground**.
That to avoid the hassle of "*Hey it is working on my side, while it is not working on another side*".

Conclusion: You must **wait** until it get **confirmed** from a maintainer to run the checks on **GitHub actions**, and your local run **cannot be replaced** with github actions.

Comment: How to run them locally?

Comment: You will have to install the dependencies of each driver and run the test command of it. Follow each driver guide, here is python driver for example https://github.com/apache/age/tree/master/drivers/python#test

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Mohamed Mokhtar's answer, you can use a virtual environment to get a neutral ground for unit tests for the python driver. This will help avoid conflicts with other packages and will give you an isolated environment to test the driver.

1. To run the drivers locally, you will first need to get the source files from [Apache Age Github][1]. You can type the following in your terminal to clone the repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/age
```

2. Next, create a virtual environment and activate it.

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

3. Install the required dependencies for the drivers as instructed in the **readme.md** files of the drivers. In case of the python driver, you can simply run the following:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

4. Run your postgres server and execute the file containing test cases.

**NOTE:**
Above instructions are python driver specific but you can follow above to test other drivers as well.
[1]: https://github.com/apache/age

Answer (score 0):

To run your test locally on drivers navigate to the `age/drivers` folder. From there you can use the read me file of each language driver on how to eun the tests locally.

For python [Python driver setup and test](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/drivers/python/README.md)

For node.js[Node.js test example](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/drivers/nodejs/README.md)

For Go [Go setup and test](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/drivers/golang/README.md)

For JDBC [JDBC setup and test](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/drivers/jdbc/README.md)

Each of the link will tell you how to set up the driver and test it. In my opinion you might want to push your changes to your own repo where the tests are run instantly through github actions as running them locally will be a lot more time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the tests locally using `Github Actions Toolkit` or `act` library.

This process is explained in the [link](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/test-github-actions-locally).

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to run drivers tests locally instead of waiting for pull request to be triggered.
You can Run the tests for each driver individually by following these steps:

- Clone the Apache AGE repository to your local system.
- Navigate to the driver folder you want to test.
- Install the dependencies required for that drivers.
- Run the appropriate command to test that driver.

There are four drivers for Apache AGE, here are some examples of How to run the tests for each driver:

**GoLand:** Navigate to the `golang` folder and run `go test`

**JDBC:** Navigate to the `jdbc` folder and run `mvn test`

**Node.js:** Navigate to the `nodejs` folder and run `npm test`

**Python:** Navigate to the `python` folder and run `python3 -m unittest discover`